# Process HTTP post sent by server

Tags: http-post

I would like to ask if anyone can give me some tips on if this is possible:

1. I'm using a POST to send some data to a server. (for the record, if I use a GET the server internally converts into POST).
2. The server is posting a reply in the browser via a POST method as well, but it is posting the data to the same page I have been redirected to after the POST - on the server-side, that is.
3. I would like to know where in my code or how, after I send the POST I can process or ask about that data received, if that is possible that is.

Just to summarize and make this simple, let's say I have a program that asks the server "hey what time is it in Australia". The server takes those parameters and posts the time and, let's say, the weather in Australia ON THE SAME SERVER. I would like to grab those data or be able to say something like "if temperature < 0 bla bla".

Is there a way a can accomplish this? I have been looking around everywhere, but cannot find what I'm looking for. I should say I have no access at all to the code in the server. I cannot believe this is not doable since the data is posted on my browser via a POST. I don't want to change anything on the server side, I just want to grab and process that response via POST from the server.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What you describe makes no sense. If a server internally converts a GET to a POST then it is doing something wrong. And it cannot POST a reply back to the client, let alone POST to a redirected URL.  A redirect is sent back to the client, and then the client decides whether to send a new GET/POST request to the redirected URL. The server does not do that.

Comment: In your example, the client sends a request to get the time.  The server sends back a reply with the time, and optionally the weather.  The server is done. The client then processes the reply as needed.  The client is done.  Your description makes that process more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: And how can  the client process the server reply? That is exactly my question. For example, something very simple: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit - When you submit, the post is sent to a server page, and it returns something. How can I grab and parse that return? Thx.

Comment: That depends on how you are communicating with the server in the first place (are you using an HTTP library, or are you using direct socket API calls?), and even what programming language you are using (to know what kind of parsing functions are available).  Since you have not provided ANY info about your development environment or project setup, there is no way to really explain how to process the response in your setup.  All I can do is suggest that you read [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) and use a packet sniffer (like WireShark) to watch how a web browser communicates.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What I am doing is just an HTTPS POST done with HTML, exactly the same way the link I have posted above. Then the server returns something, and I want to grab that response because I want to give it some format. What language I want to use? Well, that is exactly the question - I would like to know if there is a way or a language that can grab that response from the server in reply to my HTTPS POST done via HTML. I have read something about AJAX, but I do not know if that is the way to go. Thanks.